# Dataset return type with EF Function Import

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm updating old code (not written by me) to use the entity framework and LINQ. Currently it uses Codesmith. However, there are a couple function calls that are really just wrappers for stored procedures.

I tried using function import but the problem is the stored procedure returns different datasets from different tables based on the parameters it receives. Since I can't count on the return value being from a particular table or view I was hoping I could have it return a generic dataset. That is currently how the Codesmith implementation works, but we're trying to completely get rid of any Codesmith in the project. Is there a way to have a more generic return type for when you're not sure what you'll get back?

Comment: If you couldn't even create such a generic return type by hand, then  how would EF do it?

Comment: I thought that's what the DataSet type was? But I can't select DataSet as the return type in the Add Function Import dialog.

Comment: EF doesn't support DataSet. DataSet is quite old-school.

Comment: I knew I should have never "upgraded" from my abacus. :)

Comment: With dynamic output, forget EF. You could take a look at [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/#Stored_Procedures), using `Query<dynamic>`.